# /__browserLink/requestData: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Update:
after disable browserLink getting the following errors:

you pretty much posted the same time I found about this browserlink feature and I have disabled from VS IDE and also from web.config and getting the same error message 
[image]

`GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
VM1616:8113 GET http://localhost:4416/home/about net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSEDVM1616:8113 (anonymous function)VM1616:7915 sendReqVM1616:7655 serverRequestVM1616:11046 wrappedCallbackVM1616:11046 wrappedCallbackVM1616:11132 (anonymous function)VM1616:12075 Scope.$evalVM1616:11903 Scope.$digestVM1616:12179 Scope.$applyVM1265:1341 (anonymous function)VM1265:3762 invokeVM1265:1339 doBootstrapVM1265:1353 bootstrapVM1265:1301 angularInitVM1265:21048 (anonymous function)VM1264:1037 fireVM1264:1148 self.fireWithVM1264:433 jQuery.extend.ready`

UPDATE:

If I create a new Project with the http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b AngularStart Template, I get this error. My Other Project also uses Angular.

I have just started using this (AngularStart https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b) template by default when you use this template it has few menu items already added so just for the test purpose I have added a new menu item called  "Employees" and I have wired exact the same way as it has for others and when I run the app and all the links are working except the one I have added (Employees) and when I looked at it in Chrome console to see what's going on then I see very strange error as shown below, I have no idea what to take from that error messages

So here is what I have done:

in the `App_start\bundleconfig.cs` I have added:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/app/app.js",
                        "~/Scripts/app/services.js",
                        "~/Scripts/app/directives.js",
                        "~/Scripts/app/main.js",
                        "~/Scripts/app/contact.js",
                        "~/Scripts/app/about.js",
                        "~/Scripts/app/demo.js",
                        "~/Scripts/app/employees.js" //<<<NEW ADDED
                        ));
```

`Controllers`

`HomeController.cs` I have added:

```
   public ActionResult Employees()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

`Scripts/app/` I have added a new .JS file and name it `employees.js`

I have the following in it:

```
angular.module('main')
    .controller('employeesController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }]);
```

In the `app.JS`

```
var appRoot = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'ngGrid', 'ngResource', 'angularStart.services', 'angularStart.directives']);     //Define the main module

appRoot
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        //Setup routes to load partial templates from server. TemplateUrl is the location for the server view (Razor .cshtml view)
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/main', controller: 'MainController' })            
            .when('/employees', { templateUrl: '/home/employees', controller: 'employeesController' })
            .when('/contact', { templateUrl: '/home/contact', controller: 'ContactController' })
            .when('/about', { templateUrl: '/home/about', controller: 'AboutController' })
            .when('/demo', { templateUrl: '/home/demo', controller: 'DemoController' })
            .when('/angular', { templateUrl: '/home/angular' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }])
    .controller('RootController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, previous) {
            $scope.activeViewPath = $location.path();
        });
    }]);
```

Finally, I have added view in the `Views/Home/Employees.cshtml`

Anybody know what is going on? or is there any other good template out there where I can use angularjs with mvc?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/1cb60acbdd0949f08efa47be301eee7c?version=2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/cc7c21b2841b40d3836766c0b3f9319f?version=2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/cc7c21b2841b40d3836766c0b3f9319f?version=2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231439368:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/cfde8801f070426e9b4f602858301981?version=2 500 (Internal Server Error)
browserLink?_=1418231439384:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/cfde8801f070426e9b4f602858301981?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231440014:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/95c459369e354b8ea0e4afca9f1f849a?version=2 500 (Internal Server Error)
browserLink?_=1418231440030:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/95c459369e354b8ea0e4afca9f1f849a?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231440779:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/1cb60acbdd0949f08efa47be301eee7c?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231440795:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/1cb60acbdd0949f08efa47be301eee7c?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231441644:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/1cb60acbdd0949f08efa47be301eee7c?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231441660:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/1cb60acbdd0949f08efa47be301eee7c?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231442667:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/1cb60acbdd0949f08efa47be301eee7c?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231447529:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231447545:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231448923:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231448939:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231449854:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231449838:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231451929:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 500 (Internal Server Error)
browserLink?_=1418231455495:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231456556:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231460243:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231464282:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231467383:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231468447:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231471796:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231473926:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231450966:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231450950:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231451945:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231452843:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231452827:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231453752:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231453768:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231454557:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231454573:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231455511:37 GET http://localhost:4416/__browserLink/requestData/6dbde27550d64f9281632aa6c57601e6?version=2 404 (Not Found)
browserLink?_=1418231456540:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231456556:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231463120:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231463136:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231464266:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231464282:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231465356:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231465372:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231466429:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231466445:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231467367:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231467383:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231468447:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231469465:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231468431:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231469481:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231470758:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231470774:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231471796:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231471812:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231472880:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231472896:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231473942:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231473926:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pingInterval' of undefined
browserLink?_=1418231457456:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231457472:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231458402:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231458402:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231458418:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231458418:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231459315:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231459331:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231459331:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231460259:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231460259:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231460243:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231461177:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231461193:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231461193:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231462118:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231462134:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231462134:64 [12:12:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231457456:64 [12:12:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231457472:64 [12:12:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231459315:64 [12:12:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231458402:64 [12:12:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231457472:64 [12:12:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231457472:64 [12:12:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.PixelPushing.PixelPushingModeFactory.setPixelPusingMode
browserLink?_=1418231458418:64 [12:12:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231459315:64 [12:12:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
browserLink?_=1418231423128:64 [12:12:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to match method call MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.Menu.MenuBrowserLinkFactory.setVisibility
```

Comment: Check the browser network log, the view i think is return 500 server error. You see the response html to see why the error is coming. Or you can directly open the url in browser window and look at the error.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on it only applies to if I have added new link and in network tab I do not see I am getting 404 error, do you wanna try adding anew link for a test ? Perhaps to get an idea?

Comment: getting this `GET http://localhost:47847/__browserLink/requestData/d6accf22620b413eadae7c2d5b75411f?version=2 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Disable browserlink feature of VS and try it will clear these non related features http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: I have disabled from VS IDE and also from web.config and getting the same error message very frustration, have you able to duplicate? I'm using VS 2013 Update 3, I will post the error above.

Comment: In the network look check if a request specific to your view is being made and if there is any error related to it. And for the disable browserlink to work maybe you would have to restart VS.

Comment: i have posted the screen shot and i did restart my VS and created a brand new still getting the error posted above and also i will post you the console screen shot, you have not answered my question, have you able to duplicate?

Comment: It worked fine for me. Download what i have build her http://we.tl/TucLCIQrqg

Comment: thanks, whats your VS version and update?